# Android studio : when re-import the project it show's error and given a strange floders

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

while re-importing my project android studio show's plenty of errors

after cleaning and re-importing my project i have got an red circle with “J” on my java files and i'am enable to run  my project

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and rebuild it?

Comment: yes i cleaned up my project but i have got  an red circle with “J” on my java files and i'am enable to run my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by updating the version of android studio .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your gradle version is defined properly.
It seems that this project was on another PC and you imported it on your computer. I think that probably a gradle version conflict occurred and you have two options:

- one is to let android studio download gradle version specified in TlaProject (gradle 2.4)
- another solution is to edit app level **'build.gradle'** file and change its version to a version which is available on your machine (to see which version is available on your system, please check 'gradle' folder inside installation folder of android studio)